# Database - Query

Tags: database, ms-access

I have **two Database** (eg. two .mdb file).
both have same name, same table and same field.
the difference is **one is old** and **other is updated** copy of .mdb file.
**i want to copy only new records from the updated copy of the .mdb to the older one.**
is there any way other than iterate trough all the records and compare and filter only newer one?

Comment: Can't you just copy the file?

Comment: i one have application which operate on two different computer. but not maintain same copy of .mdb user on one computer may add some new record which record are new for the user on second computer. i just want copy those new record from first computer to second computer. means i want to synchronize both .mdb file

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from A 
where (col1,col2,…) not in 
(select col1,col2,… from B) 
union all 
select * from B 
where (col1,col2,…) not in 
(select col1,col2,… from A);
```

Edit: sorry, you only need to do this one way.

```
 select * from B 
where (col1,col2,…) not in 
(select col1,col2,… from A);
```